# Making a json request with javascript

Tags: javascript, json, api, python-requests

I'm making a web app that uses an API. The problem is that I never did JSON requests with javascript (I used to work with python). Here is my code :

```
<head>
  <title>IP finder pro</title>
  <script>
    function find_ip() {
      var ip = document.getElementById('ip_input').value;
      fetch('http://ipapi.co/8.8.8.8/json')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => alert(data));
}
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <input id="ip_input">
  <button id="ip_button" onclick="find_ip()">Click !</button>
</body>
```

This is the JSON file :

```
{
    "ip": "8.8.8.8",
    "city": "Mountain View",
    "region": "California",
    "region_code": "CA",
    "country": "US",
    "country_code": "US",
    "country_code_iso3": "USA",
    "country_capital": "Washington",
    "country_tld": ".us",
    "country_name": "United States",
    "continent_code": "NA",
    "in_eu": false,
    "postal": "Sign up to access",
    "latitude": "Sign up to access",
    "longitude": "Sign up to access",
    "timezone": "America/Los_Angeles",
    "utc_offset": "-0700",
    "country_calling_code": "+1",
    "currency": "USD",
    "currency_name": "Dollar",
    "languages": "en-US,es-US,haw,fr",
    "country_area": 9629091.0,
    "country_population": 310232863.0,
    "message": "Please message us at ipapi.co/trial for full access",
    "asn": "AS15169",
    "org": "GOOGLE"
}
```

And this is the curl command :

`curl 'https://ipapi.co/8.8.8.8/json/'`

Do you have any idea of how I could do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use Ajax.

```
function ajax_get(url, callback) {
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        console.log('responseText:' + xmlhttp.responseText);
        try {
            var data = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
        } catch(err) {
            console.log(err.message + " in " + xmlhttp.responseText);
            return;
        }
        callback(data);
    }
};

xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();
}


ajax_get('your url', function(data) {
  // Do stuff with it -> data["yourvalue"];
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `fetch` API for that and decode your JSON. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

```
fetch('http://example.com/movies.json')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data));
```

Comment: I think fetch is the best solution. However, you need to be aware that it is not supported by all browser or older versions of them. If you e.g. need to support crappy IE it is probably better to use some kind of http-request library.

Comment: It returns me this : `[object Object]`.

Comment: mhh.. That's odd. Can you supply your implementation of that example?

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            var Obj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            console.log(Obj);
           }
        };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "your_json_file.json", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
```